# Where can I get the correct size of a label used inside a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `TableViewCell` that contain a `lablel`. I want to check the size of the `label` when the cell is displayed to determine if the text is truncated or not. I found different topic that handle this subject but nothing worked for me. I tried to check the size in `layoutSubviews`

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    print(label.bounds.size.width)
}
```

and also to implement the `willDisplay` delegate

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
.....
print(cell.label.bounds.size.width)
}
```

I always get the same width of the label before the view is loaded (the width set on the interface builder)

**Edit:**

If I reload the tableView than I get the right size. Do you have an idea about the cause?

Comment: Rather than checking out the cells width, check out the labels width by checking its intristic concent size

Comment: I am checking the label width, not the cell

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the properties of your CustomCell you have to do something similar to this:

```
let customCell = cell as! YourCustomCellClass
print(customCell.lbl_test.frame.size.width)
```

This method can be implemented in your "willDisplay cell", if you then want to access each cell separately, then you would have to create the appropriate IndexPath for each of those cells

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing but this is always returning the same number, no matter how long the label is.

Comment: if the method returns the same value, you may have some constant value in the dimensions of the label, which causes it to always have the same length, another reason could be that the cell has not yet been deployed, so it has not yet finished. load, maybe you could try with the didEndDisplaying method

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I like to use to get the size of a UILabel with a string of text, a specific font type and width. You can update it to accommodate to your needs:

```
func sizeForLabel(text:String, font:UIFont, width:CGFloat) -> CGFrame{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.font = font
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame
}
```